# button border color is not changed on click

Tags: android, android-button

In my application I have 7 buttons ,I am trying to change the button border color when I clicked on it .By default the button color is gray and after click on it I would like to change to some other color.

gray_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#646464" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <size android:width="37dp" android:height="40dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

green_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/green" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <size android:width="37dp" android:height="40dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

CreateAlarm.java

```
    public class CreateAlarm extends Activity {

    private TimePicker mTimePicker;
    private EditText mTitle;
    private TextView mCancel, mRepeat,mSave;
    private String mselectedTime,mAlarmName,mSnoozeEnabled,mFlashLightEnabled,mVibrationEnabled,mVolumeIncreaseEnabled,mSunDay,mMonDay,mTueDay,mWedDay,mThuDay,mFriDay,mSatDay;
    private com.suke.widget.SwitchButton mSnooze,mFlashLight,mVibration,mVolumeIncrease;
    public String mSelectedDays;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        mFlashLight.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new SwitchButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(SwitchButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                if(mFlashLight.isChecked()== true){
                    mFlashLightEnabled = "Enabled";
                }
            }
        });

        mVibration.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new SwitchButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(SwitchButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                if(mVibration.isChecked()== true){
                    mVibrationEnabled = "Enabled";
                }
            }
        });

        mVolumeIncrease.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new SwitchButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                if(mSelectedDays.contains("Thu")){
                    mThuDay = "Thu";
                }else{
                    mThuDay = "Null";
                }
                if(mSelectedDays.contains("Fri")){
                    mFriDay = "Fri";
                }else{
                    mFriDay = "Null";
                }
                if(mSelectedDays.contains("Sat")){
                    mSatDay = "Sat";
                }else{
                    mSatDay = "Null";
                }
//SwitchButton isChecked Validation
                if (mSnoozeEnabled == null){
                    mSnoozeEnabled = "Disabled";
                }



                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAlarm.this, AlarmActivity.class);


    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mRepeat.setText("");
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN_ORDERED)
    public void onEventMain(AlarmEvent alarmEvent) {

        if (alarmEvent.getSelectedEventType() == AlarmEvent.eventTypes.updateSelectedDay) {
            mRepeat.setText(alarmEvent.getSelectedDays());
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        finish();
    }
}
```

**update :**

CreateAlarm.java

```
public class CreateAlarm extends Activity {

    private CustomBorderButton mbtn_Sun,mbtn_Mon,mbtn_Tue,mbtn_Wed,mbtn_Thu,mbtn_Fri,mbtn_Sat;
    public String mAlarmTitle, mTime, mSun, mMon, mTue, mWed, mThu, mFri, mSat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_alarm);

        mbtn_Sun = (CustomBorderButton) findViewById(R.id.mbtn_Sun);
        mbtn_Mon = (CustomBorderButton) findViewById(R.id.mbtn_Mon);
        mbtn_Tue = (CustomBorderButton) findViewById(R.id.mbtn_Tue);
        mbtn_Wed = (CustomBorderButton) findViewById(R.id.mbtn_Wed);
        mbtn_Thu = (CustomBorderButton) findViewById(R.id.mbtn_Thu);
        mbtn_Fri = (CustomBorderButton) findViewById(R.id.mbtn_Fri);
        mbtn_Sat = (CustomBorderButton) findViewById(R.id.mbtn_Sat);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            mTime = bundle.getString("mTime");
            mSun = bundle.getString("mSun");
            mMon = bundle.getString("mMon");
            mTue = bundle.getString("mTue");
            mWed = bundle.getString("mWed");
            mThu = bundle.getString("mThu");
            mFri = bundle.getString("mFri");
            mSat = bundle.getString("mSat");


            if (!(mAlarmTitle == null)) {
                mTitle.setText(mAlarmTitle);
            }

            if(mSun.contains("Sun")){
                mbtn_Sun.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if(mMon.contains("Mon")){
                mbtn_Mon.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if(mTue.contains("Tue")){
                mbtn_Tue.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if(mWed.contains("Wed")){
                mbtn_Wed.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if(mThu.contains("Thu")){
                mbtn_Thu.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if(mFri.contains("Fri")){
                mbtn_Fri.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if(mSat.contains("Sat")){
                mbtn_Sat.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN_ORDERED)
    public void onEventMain(AlarmEvent alarmEvent) {
        if (alarmEvent.getSelectedEventType() == AlarmEvent.eventTypes.updateSelectedDay) {
            mRepeat.setText(alarmEvent.getSelectedDays());
        }
    }

    private void finishActivity() {
        finish();
        mbtn_Sun.clearAllDays();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finishActivity();
    }
}
```

After loading this activity I received the data from previous activity and based on this I want to set the buttons are enabled/disabled and also want to set the TextView text (mRepeat) text accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is `AppCompatButton`. You should extend only `Button`.

You should research `EventBus` : https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus . It is provide that notice activity or fragment anything.

Please try again:

```
public class CustomBorderButton extends Button {

    private static HashSet<Integer> selectedDays = new HashSet<>();

    public CustomBorderButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomBorderButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomBorderButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int id = view.getId();
                boolean isSelected = selectedDays.contains(id);

                Drawable bgDrawable;

                if (isSelected) {
                    bgDrawable = getBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.gray_button);
                    selectedDays.remove(id);
                } else {
                    bgDrawable = getBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.green_button);
                    selectedDays.add(id);
                }

                setBackground(bgDrawable);
                setSelectedDays();
            }
        });

    }

    private void setSelectedDays() {

        StringBuilder repeatDays = new StringBuilder();
        TreeMap<Integer, String> mAlarmDays = new TreeMap<>();

        if (selectedDays.size() == 0) {
            repeatDays = new StringBuilder("Never");
        } else {

            for (Integer selectedDayId : selectedDays) {

                switch (selectedDayId) {

                    case R.id.mbtn_Sun:

                        mAlarmDays.put(0, "Sun");
                        break;

                    case R.id.mbtn_Mon:
                        mAlarmDays.put(1, "Mon");
                        break;

                    case R.id.mbtn_Tue:
                        mAlarmDays.put(2, "Tue");
                        break;

                    case R.id.mbtn_Wed:
                        mAlarmDays.put(3, "Wed");
                        break;

                    case R.id.mbtn_Thu:
                        mAlarmDays.put(4, "Thu");
                        break;

                    case R.id.mbtn_Fri:
                        mAlarmDays.put(5, "Fri");
                        break;

                    case R.id.mbtn_Sat:
                        mAlarmDays.put(6, "Sat");
                        break;
                }
            }//for

            for (String day : mAlarmDays.values()) {
                repeatDays.append(day).append(" ");
            }

        }

        EventBus.getDefault().post(new AlarmEvent().updateSelectedDay(AlarmEvent.eventTypes.updateSelectedDay, repeatDays.toString().trim()));
    }

    public Drawable getBackgroundDrawable(int resourceId) {

        Drawable backgroundDrawable;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            backgroundDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId, getContext().getTheme());
        } else {
            backgroundDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
        }

        return backgroundDrawable;
    }
}
```

CreateAlarm.java

```
    public class CreateAlarm extends Activity {

    private TimePicker mTimePicker;
    private TextView mCancel, mRepeat;
    private ImageView mRepeatIcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_alarm_layout);
        Utils.darkenStatusBar(this, R.color.StatusbarColor);

        mTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.mTimePicker);
        mCancel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mCancel);
        mRepeat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mRepeat);

        int hours = mTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
        mCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mRepeat.setText("");
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN_ORDERED)
    public void onEventMain(AlarmEvent alarmEvent) {

        if (alarmEvent.getSelectedEventType() == AlarmEvent.eventTypes.updateSelectedDay) {
            mRepeat.setText(alarmEvent.getSelectedDays());
        }

    }

}
```

AlarmEvent:

```
public class AlarmEvent {

    private eventTypes selectedEventType;
    private String selectedDays = "";

    public String getSelectedDays() {
        return selectedDays;
    }

    public eventTypes getSelectedEventType() {
        return selectedEventType;
    }

    public enum eventTypes {
        updateSelectedDay
    }

    public AlarmEvent updateSelectedDay(eventTypes newEvent, String selectedDays) {

        AlarmEvent alarmEvent = new AlarmEvent();
        alarmEvent.selectedEventType = newEvent;
        alarmEvent.selectedDays = selectedDays;

        return alarmEvent;
    }
}
```

### > Reply to your comment:

> CreateAlarm

```
clickSave(){

  Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAlarm.this, AlarmActivity.class);
  finish();
  startActivity(intent);
}

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
   super.onBackPressed();

   finish();
    }
```

> AlarmActivity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    finish();
}
```

Comment: there are two things goes wrong , Buttons changed the color after gets two click and the text of buttons not append in the TextView when the respected button gets clicked ,Please help me to fix it @propoLis

Comment: Yes ,I want it to be in an ordered one and the selected days will always appear in the specific position like 0 for sun ,1 for mon like that then only  if I selected the days in a random order it will appear in the particular  order  @propoLis

Comment: bro ,I need your help ,Here by using the above code I try to bind the selected buttons text to another textview ,it's working fine when I click the buttons from sun to sat but it goes wrong when I randomly select the buttons for ex : If I selected wed day after the activity gets loaded it bind all days to the textview .
please help me to solve this . @propoLis

Comment: I tried this code that works correctly even if it is random

Comment: please check like this ,after loading the activity once select all the buttons start with wed and deselect all button now close the activity .Again open the activity now select the wed it will bind all days . @propoLis

Comment: looking for your suggestion to do the next @propoLis

Comment: please look onPause function

Comment: Bro ,I have updated my  CreateAlarm.java file please check it ,I am still facing the same issue .@propoLis

Comment: please share your layout again and don't delete at question

Comment: Please check the layout design file I have updated @propoLis

Comment: bro waiting for your guidance @propoLis

Comment: I did not understand your error. I tried this: " please check like this ,after loading the activity once select all the buttons start with wed and deselect all button now close the activity .Again open the activity now select the wed it will bind all days"
But did not make an error.

Comment: once I open the app and select the buttons in a row from sunday to saturday then click the save(it will close current activity and open new activity) button It displays all the selected days in a toast .Now come back to the activity where I have the buttons now I select the button wednesday it will bind all the days in the Textview and after closing the activity by click on save button it shows all the days in the toast but I have selected only wednesday this is my problem @propoLis

Comment: Simply the problem is it works as I expected When the app gets load and I selected the the buttons for the first time ,If I select the buttons next time without closing the app it's goes wrong @propoLis

Comment: applied the changes ,but having the same issue ,Really confused @propoLis

Comment: Can you please recheck my updated CreateAlarm.java file @propoLis

Comment: Brooo,I found the same issue in the app you gave now .
Just recheck it bro,Select sunday to Saturday after the activity gets loaded then click save and come out of the application ...Again now go to the app just select Sunday alone you will get all the days instead of get sunday alone @propoLis

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy .....May I know what is the problem behind that issue .@propoLis

Comment: buddy I need your help ,Now I am trying to enable / disable the buttons based on the database values which I have stored before .But In my case I can't make it as enabled/disabled .I have updated my createalarm.java code please help me to fix it .@propoLis

Comment: I don't understand your issue , please describe that

Comment: buddy , I am not facing any issue .In this app I have two activities 1 is AlarmActivity which displays all the alarms set by the user .another one is createAlarm Activity which is used to create the alarms . Here what I want to do is when the user click(edit button) on a alarm in alarm activity that will open create alarm activity and it will shown the details of the selected alarm.For that I want to enable and disable the buttons(round buttons ).I have set all the remains (timepicker,title,etc )except the round buttons coz I have separate class and event for that ,please help me to fix it

Comment: @Nikson do you wait until monday :) I am very busy exactly

Comment: Bro ,I have finished it just now ,Thanks for your reply ,and will get you back if I have any doubts in upcoming days @propoLis

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a selector in res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/gray_button"></item>
<item android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@drawable/green_button"></item>
```

Then in your custom BorderButton instead of changing the background , just set the activated state of the button

```
if (isSelected) {
                setActivated(false);
                selectedDays.remove(id);
            } else {
                setActivated(true);
                selectedDays.add(id);
            }
```

Comment: Ahh , i get the bug now , In fact the setOnclickListener inside the class CustomBorderColor.java is not called, because you override the clicklistener inside the Activity, so you should change the background (or change the state activated) inside the activity ... did you get  it now !!!

You should set the state for each instance of CustomBorderColor
in onCLick inside the activity